# iPhone 6 iOS 9.3.2 – How to change date years back?

Tags: iphone

There are several recommendations to set back the date in order to delete some photos, but I can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Settings > General > Date & Time
Switch off Set Automatically, then tap on the date underneath.

You get a standard date/time scroller.

[image]

Comment: OK FOR DATE BUT NOT YEAR

Comment: What happens if you go back past Jan 1st? Does it just go round again? Also, what benefit could there be to setting it more than 30 days out, if all you're doing is using it to quick-delete photos, which would probably have been quicker to do by hand.